# Why is this output when compare a float and a double

Tags: c#, double, primitive

I wrote a program in c#

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        float   c = 1.111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111F;
        double  d = 1.111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111F;
        Console.WriteLine(d);
        Console.WriteLine(c);

        Console.WriteLine(c == d);
        Console.Read();
    }
```

output is:

```
1.11111116409302
1.111111
True
```

**So,Question:**
why is its output is **true**
Please help me understand this,Thanks!

Comment: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: c is the float approximation to the decimal number. d is the conversion to double of that float. As part of the comparison, c is converted to double. You are comparing the double conversion of the float approximation to a particular decimal number to itself, so of course the result is true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do the first assignment, the constant is truncated to fit the `float`. When you do the second assignment, the `float`-precision literal `1.1111...11F` is converted to `double`. Since  `c` contains the value of the `1.1111...11F` literal, initialization of `d` is equivalent to

```
double d = ((double)c);
```

Both assignments change the precision of the constant from the literal, but they change it differently. That is why you see different printouts in the first two `WriteLine`s.

When you compare `c` and `d`, the value with the lower precision, i.e. `c`, is converted to the type with the higher precision, i.e. to `double`. That is the same conversion as the conversion that has been performed when you assigned the `1.1111...11F` literal to variable `d`, so the values compare the same in the `==` operation. In other words, when you do this

```
Console.WriteLine(c == d);
```

the compiler does this:

```
Console.WriteLine(((double)c) == d);
```

That is why the comparison returns `true`.

Comment: thanks for helping me understand how compiler works